# Access AWS RDS from Pyspark EMR

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, amazon-rds, amazon-emr

I am trying to access some tables in RDS using Pyspark in EMR.

I tried installing JDBC drivers in /usr/share/java but looks like the spark is not picking up the drivers

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, jdbcPort, dbname)

hostname = "rds_host"
jdbcPort = 3306
dbname = 'demo'
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
table = "demo_table"

connectionProperties = {
  "user" : "user",
  "password" : "pass"
}

my_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='SRC_CONNECTION', properties= connectionProperties)
my_df.show()




ERROR:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mysql-connector-java-*.jar` while initializing the **pyspark** shell use `--jars .

- For **[spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876531)** using `--driver-classpath <jar_path>` argument.
- In connectionProperties add **`driver : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`**